# Permission errors with updates on new install

Tags: apt, permissions

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

andy@andy-Aspire-5750:~$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
andy@andy-Aspire-5750:~$
```

Can you please help to decipher this?

Comment: your title is your answer. you have to use `sudo`. `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get update` needs to modify the systems cache of available packages. You have to run such commands as the superuser.

Run `sudo apt update` to update the list of packages, and `sudo apt install packagename` to install a package, or `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade.